# jQueryMobile - Spinbox - Multiple dependant Spinboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

In a jquery mobile application i have to use  three dependant spinboxes as shown in image below[image]

Currently am using this plugin

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/

Maximum value for adult / child /infant is 9

Also the infant count should not be greater than adult value. i have created a validation function which will call  on click button up /down. But the change made is not affecting the other spinboxes

Below code i have set "max" attribute to infant but its not working

```
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="adult">ADULT</label>
        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-role="spinbox" name="spin4" id="adult" data-options='{"type":"vertical"}' value="1" min="0" max="9" />

        <label for="child">CHILD</label>
        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-role="spinbox" name="child" id="child" data-options='{"type":"vertical"}' value="0" min="0" max="9" />

        <label for="infant">Infant</label>
        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-role="spinbox" name="infant" id="infant" data-options='{"type":"vertical"}' value="0" min="0" max="9" />
    </div>


// id is the id of spinbox .ie adult, i=child, infant

setValidations:function(id){
        console.log("selected id="+id);
        console.log("selected id value ="+$("#"+id).val());
        $("#infant").attr("max",$("#adult").val())
        $("#infant").enhanceWithin();   
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setValidations:function(id){

            $("#infant").attr("max",$("#adult").val())
            $("#infant").spinbox({"dmax":$("#adult").val()});
            $("#child").spinbox({"dmax":9-$("#adult").val()});
            if(id == 'adult')   {
                $("#child").val(0);
                $("#infant").val(0);                                                                                           
            }
        }
```